# asp dropdownlist populated from xml list how to do add tooltips

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, tooltip

PLEASE HELP WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

I have an xml list of countries in the format of

```
 <COUNTRY value="blah" title="blah">blah blah</COUNTRY>
```

I have a asp dropdownlist thats populated from the extensive xml list and dropdownlist html format is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="mCOUNTRY" runat="server" Width="205"      onmouseover="showHideTooltip()"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

-----showHideTooltip() below-----

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function showHideTooltip() 
{
var obj = document.getElementById("mCOUNTRY");
obj.title[obj.selectedIndex].title;
}

</SCRIPT>
</CODE>
```

Comment: What problems, specifically, are you having with your code? Is the showHideTooltip function being called? Perhaps you could add an alert in there to display the selectedIndex value of the item being hovered to start debugging. But there's nothing in the code that is showing or hiding any element...

Comment: Thanks for the response the problem im having is there is no tooltip being displayed even after i call the showHideTooltip() in the onmouseover option. I'm not understanding why.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show a tooltip when the mouse is hovered over an item in your drop down list? You could assign the tooltip attribute when you bind the list from your xml?

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at this post on [show/hide tooltips with jQuery](http://ephekt.com/?p=111), you could adapt from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030383/96505), or this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313353/96505)

I *think* you would need to do something like this:

```
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none;">Content will go here</div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="mCOUNTRY" runat="server" Width="205" 
onmouseover="showTooltip()" onmouseout="hide()"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

with this for the javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function showTooltip() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("mCOUNTRY");
  var title = obj.title[obj.selectedIndex].title;
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  tooltip.innerHtml = title;
  tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible';
  tooltip.style.left = event.screenX + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = event.screenY + 'px';
}

function hideTooltip(){
  document.getElementById("tooltip").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

A jQuery solution (as mentioned above would be more elegant though)